# Same constant sprite for all Scenes in AndEngine

Tags: android, andengine

My goal is to make this two buttons constant for all Scenes, this is how it should look **(in example of browser game)**: [image]

[image]

In order to achieve this goal i had to add them in `BaseScene` like this :

```
private void populateWithOptionsButtons() {
        AudioControlTexture audioControlTexture = new AudioControlTexture();
        audioControlTexture.setPositionY(engine.getUiHelper().getDeviceHeight() - 50);
        ButtonSprite audioControlButton = engine.getSpriteLoader().
                loadStaticButtonSpriteFromName(
                        audioControlTexture.getName(), 
                        audioControlTexture.getWidth(), 
                        audioControlTexture.getHeight(), 
                        audioControlTexture.getPositionX(), 
                        audioControlTexture.getPositionY()
                );
        MakeScreenshotTexture makeScreenshotTexture = new MakeScreenshotTexture();
        makeScreenshotTexture.setPositionY(engine.getUiHelper().getDeviceHeight() - 50);
        ButtonSprite makeScreenshotButton = engine.getSpriteLoader().
                loadStaticButtonSpriteFromName(
                        makeScreenshotTexture.getName(), 
                        makeScreenshotTexture.getWidth(), 
                        makeScreenshotTexture.getHeight(), 
                        makeScreenshotTexture.getPositionX(), 
                        makeScreenshotTexture.getPositionY()
                );

        this.attachChild(audioControlButton);
        this.attachChild(makeScreenshotButton);
    }
```

But the bad thing about it is that they will be created for each Scene, my goal is : **Create them just once to use in all scenes**. Thanks for help

Comment: Not sure if it will work but look into singleton pattern. Make your button singleton class extending sprite. Then you might use it as ScreenShotButton.getInstance(). But still you will need to attach it to the scene. Never tried that.

Comment: @ŁukaszMotyczka, thanks for the reply, i've consider it, but it's not a good solution, but thanks anyway

Comment: Did you try to pass buttons to newly created scenes?

Comment: @ŁukaszMotyczka, i know it will work, but this is not a good solution for me

Answer (score 0):

Create a HUD with that populateWithOptionsButtons() logic in a "BaseScene" and attach it to that BaseScene. All your Scenes that extend that BaseScene will have that HUD.